# Need help about joining tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a MySQL database and I'm trying to create a web interface to manage tickets, right now I'm trying to list the tickets like so:
[title][name of the person that created the ticket][priority][date created][peoples that are in charge of this ticket]

so I have a table named tickets with the title, the id of the person that created the ticket, the priority, the date.

I have another table named users where you can find the first and last name and some other informations with their ID (you can link the two tables with that ID)

I have another table named tickets_users where you can find the ID of the peoples that are in charge of the tickets

My problem is I don't know how to link all of this in one request, it would be simple if only one people was in charge of a ticket but there can be multiple persons, I tried some queries but I always get tickets titles etc in double when there is more that one people in charge of a ticket.

Thanks in advance
EDIT
Example of the tables:

```
tickets:
   -id = 523 | title = help with internet explorer | priority = 3 | date = 2013-10-10 11:20:51
users: 
   -id = 25 | firstname = John | lastname = Light
   -id = 35 | firstname = Dwight | lastname = Night
   -id = 53 | firstname = Maria | lastname = Sun
tickets_users :
   -ticketid = 523 | userid = 25 | type = 1
   -ticketid = 523 | userid = 35 | type = 2
   -ticketid = 523 | userid = 53 | type = 2
```

And I'd like to be able to do a request to display:

```
[help with internet explorer][John Light][3][2013-10-10 11:20:51][Maria Sun - Dwight Night]
```

In one line (per ticket) and for all the tickets in my DB

Comment: Please post structure of table "tickets_users", then this should be easy,

Comment: It makes sense that you get the titles multiple times when there are more people assigned to a ticket. But how would you *want* or *expect* the results to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `group_concat` aggregate function to group the names of the linked persons into a single field in the result. Since I don't have your exact table structure, I've made up the names of the fields and tables.

```
select
  t.title,
  group_concat(
    case when tu.type = 1 then 
      concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname)
    end) as creator,
  t.priority,
  t.date,
  group_concat(
    case when tu.type = 2 then 
      concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname)
    end SEPARATOR ' - ') as users
from
  tickets t
  inner join tickets_users tu on tu.ticketid = t.id
  inner join users u on u.id = tu.userid
group by
  t.id;
```

If there is indeed only one creator for a ticket (which makes sense), then I would give ticket a `creatoruserid` to refer to `John`. In that case, John doesn't need to be in the junction table, and you actually don't need the `type` column any more.

Comment: That's not really readable. I suggest you take the structure I provided and fill in the proper names. If you need help with that, please put the table structure in your question and make sure it is properly aligned (use the code formatter).

Comment: Edited my first post, thanks and sorry I'm not used to stackoverflow formating

Comment: I succeded to do it but not in one request and I thing my code I really bad and not optimized, it look something like, doing a big request on tickets with a join with tickets_users, and under the request I'm doing another request in users with a WHERE usersid = "" and putting the variable from the 1st request in it, so displaying 1000 tickets will do 1000 requests...

Comment: I've changed the query a bit, using the names you provided. Especially, because you will need a case within the group_concat to make a distinction between the types of users. I hope this query works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will try that query tomorrow and will come back to you! never herd of case so maybe it's the solution to my problem, thanks again!

Comment: Seeing as my edit is now visible, I've deleted my answer to avoid duplication.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked!! And yeah only one person can create a ticket but you can add people to it, like for example if 2 or 3 people in a team have the same problem you add them in the ticket that why I needed that too for the type = 1

Comment: Hi! It's me again, I have a last question about that, I'm now displaying the user information in a user.php page, and I want to display the tickets from this user exactly like when I list all the tickets but just for this user in particular, so I took the same request and I added WHERE userid = "the user id". The problem is everything is fine but not for users and creator, since it's only for this user id it's normal that the other wont display, do you have an idea for that?

Comment: I think I do, but maybe you need to ask a new question. I cannot paste a large chunk of SQL in a comment. It won't be readable. Long story short: you must not filter by `userid`, but you need to check if a creator exists for a ticket. So you need to add `where exists (select 'x' from tickets_users tu2 where tu2.ticketid = t.id and tu2.userid = <youruserid> and tu2.type = 1)`. That will check for each ticket if `<youruserid>` is a creator for that ticket. You can change type to `2` to see if a user is a solver. Or leave out the type to see if the user is affiliated in any way to the ticket.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756439/need-help-again-about-joining-tables I created a new question, thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is I have to specify WHERE (glpi_tickets_users.users_id = ? AND glpi_tickets_users.type = 1) at the end because otherwise it will not list the tickets of that user in particular, I could do two requests but I thought it might be possible in one request, I'm stuck right now

Comment: I understand, and I think my answer solves your problem, but I've added an answer to your other question, so we can close this discussion.

Comment: Hi GolezTrol, sorry to bother you again, how can I contact you? I'd have a quick question but since there is no PM in SO I don't know how to send you a message :(

Comment: If you have a question, you can just ask a new question on SO. Then you got thousands of people who may help you and answer your question. Maybe it'll be me, probably it'll be somebody else. I can't start answering questions by e-mail or Twitter, and I won't, otherwise I won't have time for my job and my private life. :)

Answer (score 0):

I worked on problem and get the expected result.

```
select t.title,
    group_concat(
        case when tu.type = 1 then 
        concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname)
        end) as creator,
    t.priority,
    t.date,
    group_concat(
        case when tu.type = 2 then 
        concat(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname)
        end SEPARATOR ' - ') as users
from tickets t
inner join tickets_users tu on t.id=tu.ticketid
inner join users u on u.id=tu.userid  
where t.id=523;
```