# Select with condition

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I need some help about select with condition, right now I'm doing this:

```
                GROUP_CONCAT(
                    CASE WHEN glpi_tickets.users_id_lastupdater = glpi_users.id THEN
                        CONCAT(glpi_users.firstname, ' ', glpi_users.realname) 
                    END SEPARATOR '<br>') AS last_updater
```

I select firstname and realname when users_id_lastupdater = id

I guess there is a better way to do this?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: (= follow-up of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756439/need-help-again-about-joining-tables)

Comment: The problem is in my request it will only display one firstname and one realname so I'm not sure group_concat is the best way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group_concat` seems like overkill for this.  You could just use `max()`:

```
max(CASE WHEN glpi_tickets.users_id_lastupdater = glpi_users.id
         THEN CONCAT(glpi_users.firstname, ' ', glpi_users.realname) 
    END) AS last_updater
```

The separator isn't needed because it isn't used for only one element.

EDIT:

The `max()` function takes the maximum of value of an argument.  In this case, it is conditional because of the `case`.  When the condition is not met, the values are `NULL` (no `else` clause).  So, it retrieves the value when the condition is met.  If multiple row match the condition, it retrieves the largest value.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats perfect! So what does the max function exactly? it selects with condition?