# Join with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

my entire query is a bit complex so I'll try to just show what you need to understand my problem, I'm fetching tickets from a data base, it displays the title, the creator, the people in charge of the ticket, and the last updater, for the creator and the people in charge I find their `ID` in `tickets_users.users_id` and their type 1 or 2 depending if they are the creator of the ticket or if they are in charge, for the title and all the informations of the ticket itself the table is named `tickets` now for the users their ID their name etc it's `users`

So my query looks like that:

```
SELECT
tickets.id,
    tickets.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
            CASE WHEN tickets_users.type = 1 THEN 
                        CONCAT(users.firstname, ' ', users.realname)
            END) AS creator,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
            CASE WHEN tickets_users.type = 1 THEN 
                        CONCAT(tickets_users.users_id)
            END) AS creator_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
            CASE WHEN tickets_users.type = 2 THEN 
                        CONCAT(users.firstname, ' ', users.realname)
            END) AS in_charge,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
            CASE WHEN tickets_users.type = 2 THEN 
                        CONCAT(tickets_users.users_id)
            END) AS in_charge_id,
    tickets.date,
    tickets.priority,
    tickets.date_mod,
    tickets.status,
    tickets.users_id_lastupdater,
MAX(CASE WHEN tickets.users_id_lastupdater = users.id
         THEN CONCAT(users.firstname, ' ', users.realname) 
    END) AS last_updater,
tickets.content
FROM
    tickets
    JOIN tickets_users ON tickets_users.tickets_id = tickets.id
    JOIN users ON users.id = tickets_users.users_id
    WHERE tickets.id = ?");
```

My problem is there `JOIN users ON users.id = tickets_users.users_id` it works well for people in charge and creator, but if someone that is not in charge reply or modify the ticket he will not appear in "last modified by" because the `last_updater` `ID` is in the table `tickets`.
I tried to JOIN with `JOIN users ON (users.id = tickets_users.users_id AND , glpi_tickets.users_id_lastupdater)` but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: `ON users.id IN (tickets_users.users_id, tickets.last_updater)` ?

Comment: Almost working, it displays the last_updater even if he is not in charge or creator but now it's adding the last_updater to the creator or to in_charge for some reason, is there a way to do that so it will only affect the last_updater?

Comment: You'd need to add the test `AND users.id = tickets_users.users_id` to your `CASE` statements.

Comment: Everything is alright thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ON users.id IN (tickets_users.users_id, tickets.last_updater)
> ```

And

> You'd need to add the test `AND users.id = tickets_users.users_id` to
>   your `CASE` statements

Worked, thanks [eggyal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/623041/eggyal)!